# Trying to number an equation that has a piecewise function

Tags: equations

I am writing a report and I am numbering my equations. I have an equation that is a piecewise function and I do not know what I am doing wrong. This is what I have:

```
\begin{equation}
        f(r_i)=\left{
        \begin{array}{c c}
            r_i^2/2 &|r_i|\leq h
            h|r_i|-h^2/2 &\text{otherwise}
        \end{array}
    \end{equation}
```

Comment: I would suggest using `cases` instead of `array` in this case.  `\begin{equation}
 f(r_i)=
  \begin{cases}
  r_i^2/2 &|r_i|\leq h \\
  h|r_i|-h^2/2 &\text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
 \end{equation}` Note the `\\\` after the first case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There three issues with your code:

- `\left{` should be `\left\{`.
- A line break directive, `\\`, is missing at the end of the first case.
- Most importantly, a `\right.` directive is needed after `\end{array`, to serve as an "empty" counterpart to `\left\{`.

That said, you should also think about using a `cases` environment, which is tailor-made for the case at hand (pun intended).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' env.
\begin{document}
Using an \texttt{array} environment:
\begin{equation}
        f(r_i)=
        \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
            r_i^2/2 &|r_i|\leq h \\
            h|r_i|-h^2/2 &\text{otherwise}
        \end{array} \right.
    \end{equation}

Using a \texttt{cases} environment:
\begin{equation}
        f(r_i)=
        \begin{cases}
            r_i^2/2 &|r_i|\leq h \\
            h|r_i|-h^2/2 &\text{otherwise}
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}                                                                            
    f(r_i)=
    \begin{cases}
        r_i^2/2 &|r_i|\leq h \\
        h|r_i|-h^2/2 &\text{otherwise}
    \end{cases} \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

You can also use the align environment. Under tag and label you can also put custom equation numbers.

Comment: Thank you for observing that. Just edited the equation.

Comment: The positive aspect of your answer is that it uses cases (but so does Mico's existing answer, so you've not really added anything).  The negative aspect of your answer is it has a blank line in the align environment, which isn't allowed.  Also, you're not doing anything specific to align, so it should be equation; labeling by a number defeats the point of labeling;  and tagging with a number means you probably shouldn't be tagging.

Comment: I was using the tag command for a very specific reason. For example, making sure that the equation number in a report on a paper is the same equation number in the paper that the report is being written on.  The OP specifically said he's numbering the equations, so I believe this may help someone trying to add custom numbering in specific situations. Of course, if someone is writing a paper from scratch, then they should not use tag or label this way.